# How to make items collide with the floor but not with the player?

Tags: box2d, collision-detection

I want to have items (dynamic bodies) that collide with the floor (static body) due to gravity. But I don't want the player to collide with the items on the floor though I need to have a callback when the player overlaps an item (as if the item isSensor property was set to true).

Is it possible? 
I tried some configurations with the category bits and mask bits with no success.

I didn't have this problem before because items had a gravityScale set to 0 so they didn't fall on the floor. But now they need to respond to gravity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement a class that extends `b2ContactListener`. You can choose to reject the collision in `PreSolve()` virtual function. In the `b2Contact` object that is passed to `PreSolve()`, you can get the 2 fixtures, from which you can derive what it actually collides with if you have stored a pointer to the user data before.

Before you start the game engine, create new object of the subclass of `b2ContactListener`, then call method `SetContactListener()` of the game world object to set up the listener.

[Sample code](https://github.com/nhahtdh/PS5/blob/master/Game/ContactListener.mm)

Comment: And it works! I first thought I should move what I was doing in `BeginContact` to `PreSolve` because I thought `SetEnabled(false)` would prevent the call of `BeginContact`. But I only needed to disable contact in `PreSolve`so it's cool.